# clip working in Android Studio Preview but not working on device/ emulator

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The code below works perfectly on Android Studio Preview, but it becomes a square (without clipping) in emulator & real device, even clean project and re-build.

```
Column(
 Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
) {
 Box(
   modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp).height(100.dp).background(Color.Blue)
 ) {
 }
}
```

using

```
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta03"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.0.0-beta03"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.0-beta03"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta03"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta03"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta03"
```